# Tkinter module not found for Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using python 3.6. I tried to install tkinter using `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`. The result was this:

```
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
> state information... Done python3-tk is already the newest version
> (3.6.8-1~18.04).
```

However in python3 when I tried importing it with `import tkinter` and also with `from tkinter import *` It gave me an error saying no module named `_tkinter`. How do I fix this?

Note: In python 2 it seems to work fine as `import Tkinter` does not give any error, but the error occurs in python 3

Comment: No its not a duplicate, I did go through that question as well. I noted the lowercase 't' in tkinter when using python3. The problem is that the module exists on my system but python3 doesn't seem to recognize it

Comment: You are right, you can try to install with pip3.

Comment: pip3 does not install it either.  The error it gives is  `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter`

Comment: @kurag: you can't install tkinter with pip3.

Comment: go to where your python 3.6 installation is, and go to 'Lib', tell me what the tkinter folder says, is it 'tkinter' or '_tkinter'?